# JS global object, error when calling a public method

Tags: jquery, javascript-objects

I have a global jQuery object defined in an external file:

```
var App = function () {

    function handleTableRowSelection()
    {
        /*
        TRs being generated dynamically via json AJAX call. 
        Select nearest static element then pass in TRs.
        */
        $('table.allow-selection tbody').on('click', 'tr', function(e)
        {
            /*Don't change row class if clicking on a link (HTMLAnchorElement), or any other sub-element*/
            if ((e.target instanceof HTMLTableCellElement) == true)
            {
                var row = $(this);

                row.find('td').each(function()
                {
                    $(this).toggleClass('user-selected');
                });
            }
        });
    }

    return {
        init: function ()
        {
            handleTableRowSelection();
        },

    };
}();
```

When I call App.init(); in my $(document).ready it works fine (from my master blade template), even though I'm not passing any parameters to handleTableRowSelection.

When I try to call `App.handleTableRowSelection('#details', 'table.allow-selection tbody tr')` from a sub-template for a single view, I get "undefined is not a function".

I'm calling the init method in my master template like so: `App.init();`

I thought I'd be able to access the App object (my IDE code-completion finds it), is this not the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`App` is being set to an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) which returns a structure that contains `{ init: <your function> }`. No other functions are being exposed outside the IIFE - that is the *whole point* of the IIFE when used this way: To provide "private" storage for functions and to export a public interface.

If you want to be able to publicly invoke that function by that name, your last `return` needs to make it available as a property on the object it's "exporting":

```
return {
    init: function ()
    {
        handleTableRowSelection();
    },
    handleTableRowSelection: function () {
        handleTableRowSelection();
    }
};
```

Comment: Would that not call `handleTableRowSelection()` twice?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. You're returning an object with a function which invokes that function, once.

Comment: Then how does `App.init()` (in my master template) run the handle method if it's only returning it?

Comment: It doesn't; I assumed you were doing that. As it stands, what you've written would require you to run `App.init()` to invoke that function.